How to calculate hearbeat rate from audio signal using Rust?
I'm working on a digital stethoscope project and built the circuit and everything to collect audio signals from the heart. Here is the signal:

How can I measure the Heartbeat rate using these values? Here are the thing that might be useful for creating the function:
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

use crate::globals;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct DataPoint {
    x: i64, // x-coordinate, time in ms
    y: f64, // y-coordinate, amplitude
}

// Audio signal coming from an electrec mic.
// Signal oscillates around 2.5V, max 5V, min 0V
// Filters already applied but not perfect
// There is some noise in the signal but the heartbeat can be seen
// Signal vector keeps the last 5 seconds audio signal
// sample_rate = 8kHz
pub fn bpm(signal: Vec<DataPoint>) -> f64 {
    let sample_rate = *globals::SAMPLE_RATE; // f64, 8kHz
    let signal_center = 2.5;
    
    // Find BPM here
}


How would you do it without Rust?

@mkrieger1 I don't know, maybe try to create the same things in Python or Matlab and get stuck on the same topic but in a different programming language :)

This link maybe could be useful find_peaks

you haven't even provided sample data to toy with. a [mre] should come with that. -- if you're having an issue with rust, then point that out. if you're having an issue with signal processing or other scientific/engineering matters, you'd better rephrase the question language-agnostically (then probably best asked on [dsp.se]), or as a problem to be solved in Python or Methlab, sorry not sorry for the pun

Lookup "Fourier Transform" ...
